# Oracle Hierarchical query with multiple nodes

Tags: oracle, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a View and a Table that has the following details:

V_Mgmt

```
DMId    PMId    TLId
1       1       1
1       1       2
1       2       3
2       3       4
2       3       5
2       4       6
```

T_ProjLevels

```
TLId    DevId   ParentDevId
1       1       0
1       2       1
1       3       1
2       4       0
2       5       4
2       6       4
2       7       6
3       8       0
3       9       0
4       10      0
4       11      0
4       12      11
```

Ideally, my tree structure would be as per the left image. But, I am required to create a tree structure as per the right image by skipping the TL's.

[image]

So far, I was successfully able to create my tree with only DevId's by using the below query. Need some help in creating this new tree structure.

```
SELECT DevId,ParentDevId from T_ProjLevels
START WITH ParentDevId=0
Connect By Nocycle  Prior "DevId" = "ParentDevId"
ORDER SIBLINGS BY ParentDevId
```

Comment: Whar actual result format do you want? What you've shown doesn't look very useful as a result set. And is there a limit on the number of levels in the hierarchy? (And please use text  ot images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your data structure.  You have one row representing DMID 1, PMID 1, which you want to show as two separate rows in your tree.  Somehow, you need to create extra rows in your result set to represent these intermediate nodes.  A good way to do that is using `GROUPING SETS`.

So, what we will do is join the two tables and `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(...)` in such a way as to get a merged hierarchy of all the nodes, whether they are DM, PM, or DEV nodes.

Once we have that, we will just do a simple `CONNECT BY` query on the merged hierarchy.

I am pasting in a working implementation of that plan below, but first let me just say that if you need to do stuff like this often, seriously consider that maybe your data model is not properly designed.

Here is the query, with comments.  This version will give you the tree on the right in your post: that is, the one that omits the `TL` levels.  A simple modification would give the tree on the left instead... it was unclear which one you were really after (sorry).

```
-- First provide data to simulate your V_Mgmt table...
With V_Mgmt ( DMid, PMId, TLId ) AS (
SELECT 1,       1,       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,       1,       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,       2,       3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       3,       4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       3,       5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       4,       6 FROM DUAL ),
-- ... and your T_ProjLevels table
T_ProjLevels (TLId,    DevId,  ParentDevId) AS (
SELECT 1,       1,       0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,       2,       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,       3,       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       4,       0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       5,       4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       6,       4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       7,       6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,       8,       0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,       9,       0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,       10,      0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,       11,      0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,       12,     11 FROM DUAL ),
-- Next, merge them together 
--  (A) using GROUPING_SETS to create extra rows for the DM, PM, but not the TL-level nodes
--  (B) combining DM, PM, (but not TL), and DEV ids into a common set of "node", "parent_node", and "node_name" columns
merged_hierarchy ( node, parent_node, node_name ) AS (
SELECT rtrim(m.dmid || '.' || m.pmid || '.' || pl.devid,'.') node, 
rtrim(
case 
when grouping(m.pmid) = 1 then NULL
when grouping(m.tlid) = 1 then to_char(m.dmid)
when grouping(pl.devid) = 1 then m.dmid || '.' || m.pmid
else
m.dmid || '.' || m.pmid || '.' || nullif(pl.parentdevid,0) end,'.') parent_node,
case when grouping(pl.devid) = 0 THEN 'DEV' || pl.devid
when grouping(m.tlid) = 0 THEN 'TL' || m.tlid
when grouping(m.pmid) = 0 THEN 'PM' || m.pmid
when grouping(m.dmid) = 0 THEN 'DM' || m.dmid
end node_name
from v_mgmt m 
left join t_projlevels pl on pl.tlid = m.tlid
group by grouping sets ( ( m.dmid ), ( m.dmid, m.pmid), (m.dmid, m.pmid, m.tlid, pl.devid, pl.parentdevid ) )
)
-- Finally, query the merged hierarchy as a straight-forward CONNECT BY query
SELECT lpad(' ',5*(level-1),' ') || node_name output
FROM merged_hierarchy
START WITH parent_node IS NULL
CONNECT BY parent_node = prior node 
-- Exclude the outer-joined rows from T_ProjLevels...
AND node_name != 'DEV';
```

> ```
> +--------------------------+
> |          OUTPUT          |
> +--------------------------+
> | DM1                      |
> |      PM1                 |
> |           DEV1           |
> |                DEV2      |
> |                DEV3      |
> |           DEV4           |
> |                DEV5      |
> |                DEV6      |
> |                     DEV7 |
> |      PM2                 |
> |           DEV8           |
> |           DEV9           |
> | DM2                      |
> |      PM3                 |
> |           DEV10          |
> |           DEV11          |
> |                DEV12     |
> |      PM4                 |
> +--------------------------+
> ```